# Priority setting in Rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Is there any option of setting the priority in rabbit mq messaging broker.

Here is a scenario which I am stating below
Suppose you have different sites which are coming as request from external system to rabbitmq queue, and we have made that sites less than 10 will be considered as high priority and above 10 will be considered as low priority.
For this we can take two queues one each for their priority.
Now suppose I get three request with 7, 5, 2 sites. Now they will be added onto the high priority queue as all of them are less than 10.
I get another 3 request with 300,200,100 sites , these will be added to low priority queue as all of them are greater than 10.

Now if you see the order is 7, 5,2 for high priority queue but first 7 would be computed and the person who has send request for 2 site will be waiting. 
But this should not happen because the request for 2 sites should take less time compared to 7 but the order in which they have come makes it tough.

Can we have an option in rabbit mq where I can put request for 2 site first.
In the queue itself can I be able to somehow set a priority ??

Or can we multithread all the request that come to queue and run them parallely but that would increase the time I guess

Comment: Search google with `site:rabbitmq.com queue priority`

Comment: read the documentation but the problem remains same , even if i have two queue one each for low and high priority, then also in that specific range the order of incoming message is not known

Comment: "the order of incoming message is not known" - it doesn't matter. For your "high priority" queue, set the queue's max priority to 10. Then, enqueue 7, 5, and 2 with corresponding priorities 8, 5 and 3 (10 - N), and the requests will come out in that order. This is why priority queues exist. Re-read the documentation and it should be clear. Also, don't use a max priority higher than about 10.

Comment: But then how would you deal with request where sites are more than 10 like 200,150,100 ?

Comment: Use math to reduce the values into the range `1...10`.

Comment: So I guess now there won’t be any need to create two queues ? Am I right

Comment: I don't know your use-case specifically, but if you can limit the number of priority values to something reasonable and translate your incoming request priority to the queue's priority values, you should be set.

Comment: The domain here is telecom wherein request come in form of sites and sites resemble customer's address and the problem states if the number of sites are less than 10, then it is considered as low priority otherwise high priority. Now the request keeps on coming. I guess when the external system sends request to our system, then we should first prioritize that request according to (10-n) and accordingly publish to queue. BTW thanks for your earlier replies